# Geometry program not breaking out of loop when invalid input is entered?

Tags: scala

I'm doing an assignment for class which solves some basic geometry problems.

I have majority of the code working, except when a user inputs an invalid option, an infinite loop occurs and I can't figure out how to end it. Here is my code:

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

// Ask the user which problem to do
println("Please select a problem to solve.")
println("  0. Point-Circle test.")
println("  1. Circle-Circle intersection.")
println("  2. Square-Square intersection.")
println("  3. Quit.")
var choice = readInt


while (choice != 3) {

// Process the choice
if (choice == 0) {
  // Determine if circle-point intersection exists
  processPointInCircle()
} else if (choice == 1) {
  // Determine if circle-circle intersection exists
  processCircleCircle()
} else if (choice == 2) {
  // Determine if square-square intersection exists
  processSquareSquare()
} else if (choice == 3) {
  // We are done
} else {
  println("Invalid command.")
  }
}

//Functions for solving each problem

def processPointInCircle() {
  println("Please enter the values for the circle: CX, CY, and Radius.")
  val cx = readDouble
  val cy = readDouble
  val radius = readDouble

  println("Please enter the values for the point: PX, PY.")
  val px = readDouble
  val py = readDouble

  val dx = px - cx
  val dy = py - cy

  val magnitude = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
  if (magnitude <= radius) {
    println("The point lies in the circle.")
  }

  else {
    println("The point does not lie in the circle.")
  }

  println("Please select a problem to solve.\n" +
  "  0. Point-Circle test.\n" +
  "  1. Circle-Circle intersection.\n" +
  "  2. Square-Square intersection.\n" +
  "  3. Quit.")
  choice = readInt
}

def processCircleCircle() {
  println("Please enter the values for circle A: CX, CY, and Radius.")
  val x1 = readDouble
  val y1 = readDouble
  val r1 = readDouble
  println("Please enter the values for circle B: CX, CY, and Radius.")
  val x2 = readDouble
  val y2 = readDouble
  val r2 = readDouble
  val dx = x2-x1
  val dy = y2-y1
  val d = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy))
  val R = r1+r2
  val D = d-R
    if (D>0) {
      println("The two circles do not intersect.")
    }
    else  {
      println("The two circles intersect.")
    }
    println("Please select a problem to solve.\n" +
        "  0. Point-Circle test.\n" +
        "  1. Circle-Circle intersection.\n" +
        "  2. Square-Square intersection.\n" +
        "  3. Quit.")
        choice = readInt
}

def processSquareSquare() {
  println("Please enter the values for square A: Left X, Bottom Y, and Side Length.")
  val xa = readDouble
  val ya = readDouble
  val la = readDouble
  println("Please enter the values for square B: Left X, Bottom Y, and Side Length.")
  val xb = readDouble
  val yb = readDouble
  val lb = readDouble
    if (xa+la<xb || xb+lb<xa || ya+la<yb || yb+lb<ya) {
      println("The two squares do not intersect.")
    }
    else {
      println("The two squares intersect.")
    }
  println("Please select a problem to solve.\n" +
  "  0. Point-Circle test.\n" +
  "  1. Circle-Circle intersection.\n" +
  "  2. Square-Square intersection.\n" +
  "  3. Quit.")
  choice = readInt
}
```

I know that my error is occuring where the "while (choice != 3)" is, but I don't know how I could fix this as I still need to loop through the other options.

I have tried importing a utility from the standard library that allows to break the loop, but when uploading the program to Mimir, it still fails the test, so I can't use that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Learn how to debug your program!!! You are taking input choice once and then the value of the choice will never change it will go into infinite loop!!! So make sure that you take input in each case and try using match case instead of so many if else

Answer (score 0):

You just need to slightly change your logic. When the user enters an unrecognised input e.g. 4, you should just ask them to re-enter a new choice.

Hope this helps.

***Code***

```
  // Ask the user which problem to do
def getChoice: Int = {
  println("Please select a problem to solve.")
  println("  0. Point-Circle test.")
  println("  1. Circle-Circle intersection.")
  println("  2. Square-Square intersection.")
  println("  3. Quit.")

  readInt()
}

var choice = getChoice

while (choice != 3) {
  // Process the choice
  if (choice == 0) {
    // Determine if circle-point intersection exists

  } else if (choice == 1) {
    // Determine if circle-circle intersection exists

  } else if (choice == 2) {
    // Determine if square-square intersection exists

  } else {
    choice = getChoice
  }
}
```